# Cron job curl plesk 11

Tags: php, cron, plesk

I have a problem I need to start a cron job at 01:15 everyday.

this is what I set in plesk.

[image]

What's wrong? if I put in the minutes */5 work, run the cron job every 5 minutes! but if I change the data with those of the picture does not work

Comment: do they have a way to see what the real cron job looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Combining an asterisk with a forward slash and a number means 'every x number of minutes'.

That's why if you put */5 it will run every 5 minutes

In your post you mentionned:

> I have a problem I need to start a cron job at 01:15 everyday.

You did not mention AM or PM but if you want to run everyday at 01:15 PM then you should put `13` in the hour field instead of `1`.

If you want at 01:15 AM then your configuration is correct.